# diagonally reflect a matrix

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if this question has been either asked
or quite possibly already answered. If I start with
an original 3x3 matrix:

```
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
```

, how would I produce the following 3x3 matrix:

```
    9 6 3
    8 5 2
    7 4 1
```

??

Comment: Do you mean matrix transpose? (If so then my answer does that) You say that the diagonal stays the same but your example shows otherwise.

Comment: The main diagonal is the one that runs from the upper left to the lower right. "Reflecting" around the main diagonal is called _transposing_ the matrix. The diagonal that you are reflecting about (the one that runs from the lower left to the upper right) is called the _antidiagonal_ or _secondary diagonal_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to reflect about the secondary diagonal (that's NOT transposition), here's the code, a slightly modified copy of Peter's:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        int temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i];
        a[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i] = temp;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks much; I'm transposing about the secondary diagonal because I'm creating a 13x13 Ramsey Number R(4,4) counter-example using the computer instead of by hand; I needed to reflect it, so my testing algorithm will ferret out the badly-produced matrices. Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question, click the checkmark next to the answer. This is called "accepting the answer", and this is how we say "thank you" here at StackOverflow. Oh, and welcome to SO.

Comment: With your code, how do you even get to A[0][0]? Since 'j' is constrained to be always less than 'i', both of them can never be equal at the same time. The correct restriction on 'j' is j < n-1-i?

Comment: This solution is wrong and should not be accepted one. What should be: 0 <= i < n -1, 0 <= j < n - 1 - i. @Burt's solution is correct

Answer (score 4):

For an N*N square matrix :

```
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<n-1-i;j++) //Swap elements above anti-diagonal 
           std::swap(mat[i][j],mat[n-1-j][n-1-i]);  //with elements below it
```

Answer (score 3):

For a reflection, pairs of items in the matrix are swapped, so the "do something" (within the loops) will be a swap operation. Loops will be used to pick an item to swap, and some basic arithmetic is used to choose which item to swap it with. The loops should iterate over the triangle of items that are one side of the axis to reflect around, excluding those on the reflection axis and on the other side of it. To visualise that...

```
  0 1 2
0 * * /
1 * / .
2 / . .
```

The asterisks are the items to use as first parameters for the swap. The dots are the items to use as second parameters to the swap. The slashes are on the reflection axis.

Therefore...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < (n-1)-i; j++)  //  Thanks to Bugaboo for bugfix
  {
    std::swap (a[i][j], a[2-j][2-i]);
  }
}
```

With a 3x3 matrix, the loops are a bit excessive - they are shown here for the principle, and to show how to extend it. There are only three asterisks in that visualisation, and only three swap operations needed...

```
std::swap (a[0][0], a[2][2]);
std::swap (a[0][1], a[1][2]);
std::swap (a[1][0], a[2][1]);
```

Comment: With your code, how do you even get to A[0][0]? Since 'j' is constrained to be always less than 'i', both of them can never be equal at the same time. The correct restriction on 'j' is j < n-1-i

Comment: @Bugaboo - a silly mistake - my original loop would implement a transpose around the major diagonal, not the required reflection around the secondary diagonal. Looking at the history of the answer, I even referred to someone elses answer as being confused about which operation it was implementing - oops.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way in the MatLab that combines a series of other existing flipping method.

1. fliplr  (flip left and right)
2. transpose
3. fliplr

`Ham` is the target then the code is the following.
Maybe it is wrong, but let me know.

```
fliplr(fliplr(Ham)')
```